# C++ 2D Tile Engine World Loading Performance

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, 2d, tile

I have a 2D platforming game much like Terraria and is based off of millions of tiles that create the world. Right now I'm trying to find an effective method at loading only the tiles that are needed.

I have a 2D array of integers, each number associated with a certain tile texture. I save this entire 2D array, right now which is at 6509x6509. My problem is that when I start up the game and enter the world, it takes a ridiculous amount of time and memory to load the entire text file containing the 2d array. I need a way to load chunks of the world that just surround the player rather than the entire thing, and more distant parts of the world will be freed up.

Here is my code on how I load the world:

```
std::ifstream load("game_save");

int offset;

        for (int x = 0; x < 6509; x++)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 6509; i++)
            {

                load >> offset;

                world.grid[x][i].render = offset;

                load.ignore();

            }

        }

        load.close();
```

This reads the file and loads it into the 2D array

Here is the save function:

```
std::ofstream save("game_save");

    for (int x = 0; x < 6509; x++)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 6509; i++)
        {
            save << world.grid[x][i].render;
            save << " ";

        }
    }
```

I'm so confused on how to come up with an easier way to load the world. Any advice appreciated

Comment: Yes, breaking the file into chunks/tiles would be much better than trying to load all 42 million parts at once.  But **what is your question?**  It's not trivial to turn the partial code you're showing us into some kind of load-on-demand *tile manager*.

Comment: @DrewDormann I'm confused as to how, after generating the world and saving it to this file, I would go about getting the data for the chunks. I set it up where I have chunks of 120x120 blocks. In total there are 55x55 of these chunks that make up the world. I was just wondering how I can even transfer the data from the file into these smaller chunks

Comment: You could store each smaller chunk in a separate file?

Comment: @celticminstrel if I have 55x55 chunks for the entire world wouldn't that mean 3025 files? There has to be a more efficient way

Comment: That's true... I'm not sure if there're any problems with having that many files... If your tilemap were stored in a binary format, you could use seek to load a specific chunk. I'm not sure if that would be any more efficient though.

Comment: Your choice of storing the data in text-form makes a seeking algorithm difficult.. If the values were stored as `int32_t` in binary representation the load file would not only likely be smaller, the positions and chunks would be predictable. Note that platform independence would likely require something akin to a hton and ntoh massaging. Worth considering.

Comment: What's the type of a single tile?

Comment: @DanielJour it's a struct containing members for an x coordinate, y coordinate, side length and it's tile value. 0 being air, 1 being dirt, 2 being stone, etc.